# android - Run code before layout is shown

Tags: java, android, eclipse

One of the items on my app is an option who leads to another activity. Ok, I can send this option to the other activity, but I must read that option and then hide some stuff from the layout based on this info.

I have added this into the onCreate method, but no succes:

```
Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
String type = extras.getString("objects");

if(type == "animals"){      

    ImageView fieldSwamp = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.btnSwamp);
    ((LinearLayout)fieldSwamp.getParent()).removeView(fieldSwamp);

    ImageView fieldGrass = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.btnGrass);
    ((LinearLayout)fieldGrass.getParent()).removeView(fieldGrass);          

}
```

Then I tried it on the "onLocationChanged" method but no success either. I'm not sure if the problem is in the code itself or if it is where I put it. Can someone please help?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please define "no success". What problems are you having such as errors, difference between expected result and actual result, etc...?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this, because *.equalsIgnoreCase* is better for comparing strings, and it'll ignore the letters case.

```
if("animals".equalsIgnoreCase(type)){      

    ImageView fieldSwamp = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.btnSwamp);
    ((LinearLayout)fieldSwamp.getParent()).removeView(fieldSwamp);

    ImageView fieldGrass = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.btnGrass);
    ((LinearLayout)fieldGrass.getParent()).removeView(fieldGrass);          

} else {
Log.e("type","didn't remove views.");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
ImageView fieldSwamp = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.btnSwamp);
fieldSwamp.setVisibility(View.GONE);
```

Also you should use `if(type.equals(type)) {`

Comment: "Though == works most of the time with Strings". This only works when comparing the object itself. You should suggest to use `.equals()` only unless they want to compare if those two objects are equal. Also, `"animals".equals(type)` is safer as it protects against `NPE`

Comment: yes. you are absolutely right. Thanks for correcting me on this one.

Comment: yes. that should work, as the intent data is already there at that point.